# jQuery mobile : JSONP request using $.ajax(), $.getJSON not firing callback function

Tags: jquery, ajax, mobile

I try to get JSON data from my web server but it doesn't work.

```
$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();
//$.getJSON('http://localhost:8000/'+site+'/?format=json&callback=?', {}, function(){alert();});

$.ajax({
    url : 'http://localhost:8000/'+site +'/?format=json&callback=?',
    type : 'GET',
    dataType : 'jsonp',
    jsonp : 'callback',
    success : function(){alert('success');},
    error : function(){alert('fail')}
});
```

`$.getJSON`, `$.ajax` two method's callback function didn't firing at all.
What's the problem?

My web server's code:

```
response_data.append({
            'user_nickname' : post.user_nickname,
            'title' : post.title,
            'recommend' : post.recommend,
            'oppose' : post.oppose,
            'date' : str(post.date),
            'hit' : post.hit,
            'commentcount' : post.commentcount
            })
    return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(response_data), mimetype='application/json')
```

In the insepector, it returns `get`, 200, ok, so `HttpResponse` has no problem.

Here is response:

> [{"hit": 5, "title": "
>   \uc624\ud1a0\uc774\uc2a4\ucf00\uc774\ud551 \ub418\ub294\uac00",
>   "commentcount": 0, "oppose": 0, "recommend": 0, "date": "2012-07-24
>   07:01:22.453000+00:00", "user_nickname":
>   "\ud55c\uae00\ub85c\uc5bc\ub9c8\ub098\uae38\uac8c\uae4c\uc9c0\uac00\ub2a5\ud558\ub7ef\uc778\u3131\u3147\u3139\u3147\ub05d"},
>   {"hit": 4, "title": "\uc5ec\uae30 \uae00\uc4f0\uba74?",
>   "commentcount": 1, "oppose": 0, "recommend": 0, "date": "2012-07-24
>   06:52:05.125000+00:00", "user_nickname":
>   "\ud55c\uae00\ub85c\uc5bc\ub9c8\ub098\uae38\uac8c\uae4c\uc9c0\uac00\ub2a5\ud558\ub7ef\uc778\u3131\u3147\u3139\u3147\ub05d"}]

`$.ajax()` never fires the success callback function. it just calls error's `alert('fail');`

Comment: do you have a javascript function callback? (as in function callback() { alert('hello'); } )?

Answer (score 2):

Your response isn't JSONP: it's just a JSON array.

If you change the `datatype` in your `ajax` call to `'json'`, then your callback should fire.

But if you really need to use JSONP - if you're trying to do cross-site communication - then you'll need to return valid JSONP as your server response. Your server will need to respond with a string in the form of a javascript function call, using the value of the `jsonp` parameter as the function name, and the JSON response as the function argument.